# What does this three.js program do?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is a one liner, I went through documentation couldn't find anything as new capsule. I get the gist of it, it creates a new capsule but what exactly are the inputs to it? Can anyone please explain?

```
const playerCollider = new Capsule( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 30, 0 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 11, 0 ), 5 );
```

Comment: 'examples/games_fps.html' @Calculuswhiz

Comment: Oh, I see. The source code is here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/math/Capsule.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Capsule` is an experimental class in the `examples` directory and a simple form of a collider. It is made of two half-spheres joined together by a cylinder.

The ctor of the  class has three parameters:`start`, `end` and `radius`. The first two define the height of the capsule whereas the last one defines the extrusion of the capsule at the start and end.